# Insert HTML element between multiples li in jQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, append

I have several div and I try to add more around all 3 elements with append in jQuery :

I have :

```
<div>1</div>
<div>2</div>
<div>3</div>
<div>4</div>
<div>5</div>
<div>6</div>
<div>7</div>
<div>8</div>
<div>9</div>
```

And I try to insert other div like that :

```
<div class="container-1">
    <div>1</div>
    <div>2</div>
    <div>3</div>
</div>
<div class="container-2">
    <div>4</div>
    <div>5</div>
    <div>6</div>
</div>
<div class="container-3">
    <div>7</div>
    <div>8</div>
    <div>9</div>
</div>
```

I tried with append function but it no work, I don't know if is possible ?
Then, I know I need a for loop for this.
Thank you for your help.

Comment: It's not clear what you want to end up with. Can you post the desired end result?

Comment: Your question is not clear. What did you try?

Comment: Where is `li` in the markup, You should add more description about the problem.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You may loop over the existing `div`s and append them to containers.

In the iteration, you can keep track of the current container. If the container's inner element's count exceeds 2, create a new container.

This goes on until all the `div`s have been moved to containers.

```js
var container, count = 0;

$('div').each(function() {
  if (!container || container.find('div').length > 2) {
    container = $(`<div class="container-${++count}"></div>`).appendTo('body');
  }
  
  $(this).appendTo(container);
});
```

```css
div[class^=container] {
  border: 1px dashed darkgray;
  padding: 5px;
  margin-bottom: 5px;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div>1</div>
<div>2</div>
<div>3</div>
<div>4</div>
<div>5</div>
<div>6</div>
<div>7</div>
<div>8</div>
<div>9</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

You can surround all those `div`s with a container `div`, say `div` with `id = 'container'` then you can loop over all the `div` and then get  the `outerHTML` of each element and group each three `div` in a separate `div`.

```js
var nHTML = '', finalHTML = '', i=1;;
$('#container div').each(function(index, elem){
  if(index == 0 || index % 3 !==0){
    nHTML += elem.outerHTML;
  }
  else{
    finalHTML += '<div class="container-'+i+'">'+nHTML+'</div>';
    i++;
    nHTML = elem.outerHTML;
  }
});
$('#container').html(finalHTML);
```

```css
.container-1{
  color: green;
}
.container-2{
  color: red;
}
.container-3{
  color: blue;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id='container'>
  <div>1</div>
  <div>2</div>
  <div>3</div>
  <div>4</div>
  <div>5</div>
  <div>6</div>
  <div>7</div>
  <div>8</div>
  <div>9</div>
<div>
```